# Error while selecting important features in MultinomialNB

Tags: python

The following is my code:

```
feature_names1 = np.hstack([text_bow_train,title_bow_train,X_train_cat_ohe,X_train_subcat_ohe, X_train_state_ohe, X_train_pre_ohe, X_train_grade_ohe, "Price","Number of Previously posted project","Quantity"])

def most_important_features(vectorizer, classifier, n=5):
    class_labels = classifier.classes_
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[:n]
    topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[-n:]

    for coef, feat in topn_class1:
        print(class_labels[0], coef, feat)

    for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
        print(class_labels[1], coef, feat)


most_important_features(feature_names1, mnb)
```

I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'

Comment: `np.hstack` doesnt have an method / atrribute named `get_feature_names`. What are you trying to get?

Comment: I am trying to get feature name associated with the values

Comment: to get the feature names, you need to create a variable to hold your feature names before training, and then use the created variable later.